# update seperate records with a single button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code of a table here:

```
while($record=mysql_fetch_array($myData) )  {
    echo "<form action=mydata3.php method=post>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Name']  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Surname']  . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . "<input type=checkbox name=attendance value=". $record['Attendance'] . " </td>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo"<tr>";
    }
```

I would like I click the attendance button to update the records of the sql database.
If the checkbox of each student is checked the the value of attend should be Yes if is not checked it should be No. I managed to do something but is getting the checkbox value of the first student and it gives it to all the students.

Function:

```
if (isset($_POST['updatesec'])) {

    $sql = " SELECT * FROM students";

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con) {
        die("Cannot connect:  " . mysql_error());
    }

    $myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
    while ($students = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
        $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE students SET Attendance=' " . check() . " ' WHERE  Id=$students[Id]";
        mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
    }
}

Function check() {
    if (isset($_POST['attendance'])) {
        return 'yes';
    } else {
        return 'no';
    }
}
```

update: I have change the code as follows

```
while($record=mysql_fetch_array($myData) )  {
echo "<form action=studentstable.php method=post>";
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Name']  . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Surname']  . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . "<input type=checkbox name='attendance[".$record['Id']."]' value='". $record['Attendance'] . "' /> </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo"<tr>";
}


if (isset($_POST['updatesec']))  {

$myData = mysql_query( $sql,$con);
while ($students = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {



   $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE students SET Attendance=  '" . check($students['Id']) . " ' WHERE  id=$students[Id]";
   mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);



}


}




Function check($id) {
        if (isset($_POST['attendance'][$id])) {
           return 'yes';
        } else {
           return 'no';
        }
     }
```

But is still only working for the first check box of the table

Answer (score 0):

U need to change the name of your checboxes and your check function:

```
    function check($id) {
        if (isset($_POST['attendance'][$id])) {
           return 'yes';
        } else {
           return 'no';
        }
     }


echo "<td align='center'>" . "<input type=checkbox name='attendance[".$record['Id']."]' value='". $record['Attendance'] . "' /> </td>";
```

This way will u have an array of all the checkboxes with a link to the id of the attendant.

```
while ($students = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE students SET Attendance=' " . check($students['Id']) . " ' WHERE  Id=$students[Id]";
    mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
}
```

On a sidenote. mysql_* functions are deprecated. U should move on to mysqli or PDO and start using prepared statements

Comment: Are you sure this will work ? name=attendance[id] ? 
I think this does not make sense , it would be better to change it to : name=attentandt_.$id